# Issues posting a form using python

Tags: python, http, post, urllib2, urllib

I'm using a combination of urllib, urllib2  to POST some form data.

Here is the form I need to submit

```
<form method="post" action="show_bug.cgi">
            <input type="hidden" name="ctype" value="xml">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="788604">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="793892">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="823569">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="823585">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="825904">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="827493">
            <input type="hidden" name="excludefield" value="attachmentdata">
            <input type="submit" value="XML" id="xml">
</form>
```

I'm creating a list of tuples of the form `[ (name,value), ... ]`

Since the submit type element has no name, I have no idea how and if to send that element using urllib/urllib2.

When I try posting this data to show_bug.cgi, I get an HTTP404 Error.

I'm confused about how to POST the form, especially the submit input type. So far I've always assumed that the value and id of the Submit type never mattered, and so far it seems to have worked for me.

---

This is the post request as captured by TamperData

[image: POST parameters]

Comment: have you tried to use [Bugzilla API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API)?

Comment: I didn't know about this. Ouch.

But the issue still seems to stand. Why is the POST request returning  a HTTP404?

Comment: Does it return 404 if you submit the form using a browser?

Comment: Btw, have you looked at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize)? Basically, you can programmatically open a web page and submit a form using it.

Comment: @JFSebastian, no, it returns the correct expected output in the browser.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev Although mechanize seems like overkill for such a simple task, if this doesn't work out, I will be using mechanize.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian re: Bugzilla API, it is present but it returns data in JSON rather than XML, although it's possible to switch from XML to JSON for my purposes, I still want to know if this way is possible, and if not why.

Comment: if you can edit the request then try to remove one by one cookies, referer, user-agent, accept headers and see when it stops working.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian   I tried removing everything. I only get an issue when I remove the host. And even then it's an extra request being sent out, and aborting that request causes no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following request works:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen


url = 'https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi'
data = urlencode([('ctype', 'xml'), ('id', [788604, 793892]),
                  ('excludefield', 'attachmentdata'),
                  ], doseq=True)
response = urlopen(url, data)
print(response.code) # -> 200
xml = response.read()
```

if `doseq=True` then `('id', [788604, 793892])` is encoded as `id=788604&id=793892`.

Without `doseq`, `('id', 788604), ('id', 793892)` produce the same result.

Comment: So far I have been omitting it completely and it doesn't seem to working for me.

Comment: Can you also explain the use of doseq? I can't seem to understand what it's for and when it should be used. The python docs aren't very elaborate either.

Comment: @Ayos: I've add explanation of `doseq=True`.

Comment: when using a list of tuples of the kind (id,value) , this seems to done automatically.

Comment: @Ayos: "doesn't seem to working for me" is not very specific. The web-page might generate additional parameters using javascript (or it might remove some parameters). The server might check User-Agent http headers, etc. Submit the form using a browser,look at the http request that it sends e.g., using a network sniffer, and [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15347248/edit) to include the sniffed http POST request that works.

Comment: @Ayos: yes. I've add a note.

Comment: @Ayos: I've tried the code from the answer and it works (status 200).

Answer (score 3):

What about [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library?

It makes things more simple, see [docs](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) on how to make a post request.

I guess you should do smth like this:

```
import requests

host = "my_host/"
url = host + "show_bug.cgi"

params = {'ctype': 'xml', 
          'excludefield': 'attachmentdata',
          'id': [788604,...,827493],
          'xml': 'XML'}
response = requests.post(url, data=params)
```

Comment: I purposely took the decision not use the requests library. I want this to be a learning exercise.

Comment: How does the submit param correspond to the dict entry `'xml' : 'XML'` ?

Comment: `id` value is incorrect, use `id=[788604, 827493]` instead. Also the order of parameters might matter and `dict()` looses that info.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev I tried both `'submit' : 'XML'` and `'xml' : 'XML'` Neither worked out.